# Issue with BigDecimal value in groovy : Retrieving diff value

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails, groovy, grails-orm

I am using Groovy/Grails framework, I am fetching the Bigdecimal value from the mysql DB using the

```
Query = "select d.quantitativeData FROM MyTable d where d.segment.id = " + segmentid + 
" and d.sustainabilityIndicatorSubQuestion.id = "+questionid+" and d.tenantId= " +
TenantUtils.getCurrentTenant()+" order by d.id desc",[max:1]"
```

quantitativeData  is a Bidgecimal variable.

But the value is retrieved from this query is like "0E-20" format, but the value in the database like '121.00000000000' , How to resolve this, can anybody help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i hope your string concating of the query does not leave you open to SQL injections

Answer (score 2):

The `BigDecimal` is being converted to the string `"0E-20"`, because you're constructing the query by concatenating strings together, rather than by using `?` query placeholders.

If you use placeholders instead of string concatenation it will resolve this problem and also make you immune to SQL injection attacks.